# Find Preferred Network mode in android programmatically

Tags: android, networking

I need to find preferred network mode in android. I have used following code but it in devices it returns SettingsNotFoundException.

```
android.provider.Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), "preferred_network_mode");.
```

Comment: what do you mean by `preferred network mode`? is it 3g, 4g, gsm, edge, etc?

Comment: It is Preferred Network mode  from settings of Device we need to captured it programmtically in Application

Answer (score 1):

It is not a secure setting, but a global one. You can access it through:

```
android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), "preferred_network_mode");
```

For more information refer the Android source code here: [Settings.Global.PREFERRED_NETWORK_MODE](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#PREFERRED_NETWORK_MODE)

---

**EDIT**

If the device has not registered to a network yet, this is what is returned:

> RIL_E_OP_NOT_ALLOWED_BEFORE_REG_TO_NW = 9,  /* data ops are not allowed before device registers in network */

For more information read the source code here: [ril.h:118](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/hardware/ril/include/telephony/ril.h#118)

Comment: I have implemented this code .It gives preffered network type values only in sony device and in other devices it gives only a value 9 always whether if i selected 2g ,3g or 4 g network .

Comment: Maybe the SIM cards in those other devices don't support multiple modes?

Comment: Or the devices didn't have SIM cards at all?